# NetworkStream doesn't support seek operations

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming, tcpclient

I'm creating simple proxy server but I faced a strange situation, I've following code :

```
var clientRequestStream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
var requestHeader = clientRequestStream.GetUtf8String();
```

`GetUtf8String` is a extension method for `Stream` class which reads stream (contains `HttpRequest` headers). I need to extract those headers to access Host and Requested Url. Once reading NetworkStream is done. I need to perform seek operation and set its `clientRequestStream.Position = 0;` because I've to read that stream and write it on another remote `NetworkStream`.

I don't know how should I solve this problem.Any advice will be helpful.

---

**Edit:** I also tried copy NetworkStream to MemoryStream then perform seek operation on MemoryStream, There is no exception but when I want to read from NetworkStream its buffer always is always empty.

Also I used reflector to see what happens inside `Stream.CopyTo`. See below code :

```
    private void InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, int bufferSize)
    {
        int num;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        while ((num = this.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            destination.Write(buffer, 0, num);
        }
    }
```

This is what CopyTo doing. Even if I use `CopyTo` Problem is still unresolved. Because it reads source (Here NetworkStream) to the end. I there another way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you reading from this stream until the end? If so, I suggest you just copy the entire contents into a `MemoryStream`, then you can seek on *that* to your heart's content. In .NET 4 it's particularly easy with [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx):

```
MemoryStream dataCopy = new MemoryStream();
using (var clientRequestStream = _tcpClient.GetStream())
{
    clientRequestStream.CopyTo(dataCopy);
}
dataCopy.Position = 0;
var requestHeader = dataCopy.GetUtf8String();
```

It makes sense for `NetworkStream` not to be seekable - it's just a stream of data that a server is giving to you. Unless you can tell the *server* to rewind (which only even makes sense in some situations) there's no way of seeking unless something buffers as much data as you need to rewind - which is basically what copying to a `MemoryStream` does, in a pretty brute-force fashion.

Comment: Jon i did copy NetworkStream to MemoryStream, but when I want to read that the buffer is always empty.

Comment: Jon I also tested CopyTo but it takes a day to copy buffer to MemoryStream. I don't know why.

Comment: @SaberAmani: Well what's in the network stream? It won't finish copying if the server keeps the connection open. As for your first comment - that would suggest that you weren't copying the data correctly. It's hard to say how without seeing your code.

Comment: @SaberAmani: You still haven't really described your situation, in terms of what the server is going to send, or when the stream is going to end. If the server is going to keep the connection open, you'd need to know how much to read and read *only that much*.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet. In my program when I wanted to use `netStream.CopyToAsync` more than 1 time, it return a file with zero size in second use of the `netStream`. I tried to seek the `position` of the `netStream` to 0 but it gave me this error: `This stream does not support seek operations`. So I used your code to made a `MemoryStream` form the `netStream` and now it works well. 

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, `NetworkStream` is not seekable.
`NetworkStream` feeds you data directly from the network.

You should read the data into a `MemoryStream` and re-use that.

Comment: You can't assign the MemoryStream to the NetworkStream.  You need to use the MemoryStream directly.

Comment: I also tested CopyTo but I takes a day to copy buffer to MemoryStream. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to properly rewrite your GetUtf8String method to not require seek...

The easiest approach would be to copy stream to MemoryStream first and than you have stream you can seek as much as you want. [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) will take care of copying (.Net4+)

Note that you need to seek resulting MemoryStream back by setting Position property to 0 (`copiedStream.Position=0`) or cloning the stream by creating new one (preferably read only) based on buffer and length of first memory stream.

Comment: @SaberAmani, Updated. Note that Jon Skeet's answer (+1) contains exact code you need.

Comment: I also tested CopyTo but It takes a day to copy buffer to MemoryStream, application stops right where I want to copy. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to set clientRequestStream.Position = 0 because NetworkStream is forward-only. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.position.aspx

Be careful about thinking of NetworkStream in the same way as regular streams. Things like Peek() for example on a StreamReader can cause your application to block.