# This stream does not support seek c#

Tags: c#, networkstream

I am pretty new to `NetworkStream` and I can't figure out why am I getting the following errors:

- length - this stream does not support seek
- Position - this stream does not support seek

I have read a few articles and the documentation, however, this is a little vague.

My current code is:

```
        public static string ReturnedMessage;

        public static void Connect(String server, String message, Int32 port)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                Byte[] messageData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();             

                stream.Write(messageData, 0, messageData.Length);

                // MessageBox.Show("Message Sent");

                messageData = new Byte[1024];

                String responseData = String.Empty;

                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(messageData, 0, messageData.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(messageData, 0, bytes);
                ReturnedMessage = "Received: " + responseData;

                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                ReturnedMessage = "ArgumentNullException: {0}" + e.ToString();
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                ReturnedMessage = "SocketException: {0}" + e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I have seen a few posts regarding `MemoryStream` but this seems to be mainly used for `HTTP`. Any help would be appreciated.

The stack for the message is as follows:

```
-       Length  'stream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'   long {System.NotSupportedException}

'stream.Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
    "at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.get_Length()"
```

Comment: This was asked many times: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11749036/1997232), [click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23321619/1997232), ...

Comment: At which line do you get these errors?

Comment: @HugoRune,when looking at the debug the error looks to be under `NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();  `

Comment: Post the *full* exception including the call stack.

Comment: The code you posted is copied from [TcpClient's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx). There's nothing wrong with it. *Is* there a TcpServer listening on the other end though?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have added the error from the debug hope this helps. There is also a TCP server and the connection seems to be fine

Comment: @Tom you *haven't* posted the full exception, only a small part of the call stack. Anyway, it shows that the problem is a call to `stream.Length`. Without the full text it's impossible to guess where the problem occured, it's certainly *no* in `GetStream()` though. Are you sure this isn't raised by your "server" code?

Comment: BTW MemoryStream isn't used for HTTP. It's used to read/write into memory buffers using a stream interface, or cache data to memory.